# is there a sort of isset() on .NET/C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to check if there is a param on the uri request.

So I need to check if that param is set. Is there a function on .NET/C#?

Comment: More info, please. Are you in a web application and handling a request? “uri request” doesn’t really make sense.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

An unset value will be null or empty:

```
value = Request["param"];
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(value))
{
    // param is not set
}
```

If the param name is in the query string but the value is not, it will be empty. If the name is not in the query string, the value will be null. For example.

```
&param1=&param2=value 
// Request["param1"] is String.Empty
// Request["param3"] is null
```

Comment: I'd consider a parameter that contains the empty string as set. Your code doesn't

Comment: Depends on your requirements. In `&param1=&param2=value` I would consider param1 unset.

Comment: param1 is set to an empty string. Whether that should be considered the same as unset or not is requirement-dependant, but it's still set.

Comment: Actually, if you are talking about PHP, isset() allows empty values, so the answer is equivalent to empty() method.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [HttpUtility.ParseQueryString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms150046.aspx) utility method which returns [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) and then cust call [Get()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s8e7f4s6.aspx):

```
bool contains = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query)
                           .Get("ParameterName") != null;
```

> **Get() method**
>
> Returns A String that contains a comma-separated list of the values associated
>   with the specified key from the NameValueCollection, if found;
>   otherwise, null

**EDIT:**

If you have an instance of the HttpRequest then just use built in indexer like below:

```
bool contains = Request["ParamName"] != null;
```

Comment: uti? how can I retrieve the actual uri?

Comment: You've asked about URI "`uri request`". If you have a HttpRequest  just use built in indexer like `Request["ParamName"]`

Answer (score 0):

In c# not implemented object is NULL. But if you try to acces to this object you will get the exception. You cat try to catch it or just add @ before your variable.
So C# isset looks like this (for array of strings)

```
// Isset
internal static bool isset(String[] m, int index)
{
    return (@m[index] == null) ? false : true;
}
```

Use it like this: `if (App.isset(parts, 1)) cat = parts[1];`
Or just "in plase" solution

```
if (@parts[1] != null) cat = parts[1];
```

I hope this ansver will help you.

Answer (score -5):

You could use try and catch to wrap your uri request?

catch for NullReferenceException or just exception?

Comment: catching an exception is not good things, instead of you can handle it, so that exception not raised

Comment: Yes I agree is not the right choice. It's another solution in case if there's no other easier way to handle it.